# accessing a textview inside a row of a listview in xamarin.android

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I've created a listview that contains 5 textviews in each row. now I want to click on the last textview and get redirected to a new page. my problem is that I can't figure out how to access the textview. I tried doing this in my custom adapter:

```
var t = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5);
            t.Click +=delegate {
                Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(context, t.Text, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
              

            };
```

I used the toast just to see if the function will work. but It didn't. when I ran the app and clicked on the textview, I kept getting a toast and it didn't stop. what is the right way to do this?
thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to the listview item reuse, please create a following class.

```
 public class LocalOnclickListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            HandleOnClick();
        }
        public System.Action HandleOnClick { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your GetView Method, use it like following code. It will make the click event execute only once in TextView.

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = mainActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null);
          
            TextView textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            textView.Text = items[position];
         

            var local = new LocalOnclickListener();
            local.HandleOnClick = () =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };

            textView.SetOnClickListener(local);
            return view;
        }
```

Or you can simple use following code.

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = mainActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout1, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.My_textView1).Text = items[position];
            TextView textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            textView.Text = items[position];
            // textView.Click += TextView_Click;


            if (!textView.HasOnClickListeners)
            {
                textView.Click += (o, e) =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(mainActivity, "click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                };
            }


           
            return view;
        }
```

Here is a similar thread, you can refer to it:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9244/single-click-on-button-invoking-multiple-clicks